# Mac OS terminal script file variables (.command)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm fairly new to writing scripts on Mac OS so apologies if the answer is fairly obvious.

I want to add a date variable to my script on Mac OS that will output the current date in YYYYMMDD format.

On Windows I would write this as:

```
set now=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
%now%
```

How would I do something similar when writing a .command file on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this in a terminal/bash script

```
myDate=$(date +%F) 
echo $myDate
```

It outputs a date like:

```
2021-05-21
```

Alternatively you can specify a formatter:

```
myDate=$(date +%Y%m%d) # to remove the dashes
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in bash 4.1 or 4.2, the builtin `printf` can emit the formatted time:

```sh
printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' -1      # => 20210521
```

Since MacOS ships with bash 3.2 by default that means you'll need to install a newer version yourself. With [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) that is as easy as `brew install bash`